Magical academy book where the female lead gets sent to a magical school and has relations with 3 or 4 other guys
The female lead destroys a city, then gets sent to a magical school and her male best friend gets in as well. She has strong feelings about 3 or 4 other guys at the school and has sex with them. One is a wolf shifter, one is really good at computers, one is called Dash. They are attacked at school by witches who steal her power. A powerful warlock is trying to capture her for her power.

In roughly which year did you read this?

Do any of these ring a bell? - https://www.jennysandiford.com/book-reviews-latest/magic-academy-book-series

You can accept a correct answer by giving on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Possibly Legacy of Shadows by Tessa Hale, first book of the Supernaturals of Castle Academy series.


All I wanted was to keep my head above water. To survive long enough to hit my eighteenth birthday so I could escape the nightmare that my homelife had become. But all of that was turned upside down the moment they showed up.
The best friend from my past. The surly brooder. The kind-hearted nerd. The king of campus. The dark one.
They say they’re here to give me a fresh start in a place where I’m safe, warm, and cared for. And I can’t deny the pull I feel to all five of them. The buzz that lights beneath my skin when they touch me. And for the first time, I feel like I might belong.
But not everything is as it seems. These guys have secrets. Ones that will rip my world wide open. But when a dark evil begins stalking us, we’re all in for the fight of our lives…

There's a wild, a dragon, and a demon. One of the guys is indeed named Dash. Found with a search for magic academy reverse harem "dash"
